# cin.ignore not working: further inputs get skipped even with clear()

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a checked bool input, but for some reason it keeps getting into an infinite loop, or (if I move `std::cin.ignore()` to be first thing executed after `std::cin.clear()`) asks for phantom input. I tried simple `ignore()` and `ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n')` and it still gets into an infinite loop, seemingly skipping `cin` input

Code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::string testString = "testvar";
    bool value = false;
    do
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "Enter " << testString << " value (true/false)\n";
        std::cin >> std::boolalpha >> value;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        if(!std::cin.fail())
        {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "Error! Input value is not boolean! Try again.\n";
    }while(true);

    std::cout << value;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is your order of operations.  With

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cout << "Enter " << testString << " value (true/false)\n";
std::cin >> std::boolalpha >> value;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

You call `clear`, get input, and then ignore the leftovers.  The issue with that is if the get input part fails, then the ignore the leftovers will also fail as the stream is in a failed state.  What you need to do is get the input, clear any error away, and then ignore an extra input.  That would look like

```
std::cout << "Enter " << testString << " value (true/false)\n";
std::cin >> std::boolalpha >> value;
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

but this will break how your loop works.  To get that working, you can use

```
do
{
    std::cout << "Enter " << testString << " value (true/false)\n";
    if (std::cin >> std::boolalpha >> value)
        break;
        
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cout << "Error! Input value is not boolean! Try again.\n";
} while(true);
```